# Is there any way to disable a flyout appearance on a content page depending on binding property in .NET MAUI?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, maui

I am developing a multipage app in .NET MAUI, and want the flyout menu to be available depending to the bindable property in view model on a specific content page.

I tried to use

```xml
<Shell.FlyoutBehavior>
    <FlyoutBehavior />
</Shell.FlyoutBehavior>
```

but it doesn't contain definition for "Disabled" .

I think it should look like

```xml
<FlyoutBehavior="{Binding Value}" />
```

Here is what I have now

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="PlumbingCompany.Views.Page1_JobOrder"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:PlumbingCompany.Data"
             xmlns:Models="clr-namespace:PlumbingCompany.Models"
             x:DataType="viewModels:Page1ViewModel"
             Title="1. Job Order">

    <Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
        <BackButtonBehavior Command="{Binding BackToListCommand}"/>
    </Shell.BackButtonBehavior>

    <Shell.FlyoutBehavior>
        <FlyoutBehavior >
    </Shell.FlyoutBehavior>

    <Page.Resources>
    </Page.Resources>
        
    <ScrollView>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Please describe the scenario you're trying to cover. What is `Value` going to be and in which cases do you want to disable the Flyout?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Shell.FlyoutBehavior` like below and set the bindable property: `Value` in your ViewModel on a specific content page. Note that `Shell.FlyoutBehavior` can only be set to `Disabled`, `Flyout` and `Locked`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.MainPage"
             Shell.FlyoutBehavior="{Binding Value}">

    <!--Omitted for brevity -->

</ContentPage>
```